# File system permissions in a docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu

How does docker create a file system for a Linux container? And how are permissions set up on the root file system?

I encountered a situation when starting a docker container on a particular machine with Ubuntu Server. For some reason, `/tmp` in the container doesn't have write permissions:

```
$ docker run -it python:3.11-slim-buster /bin/bash
root@5d5fefe9b9a2:/# ls -la /tmp
total 8
drwxr-xr-t 1 root root 4096 Jan 26 06:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jan 29 04:31 ..
```

Note that this has 755 permissions.

However, when I start the same docker image as a container on WSL, I get 777:

```
$ docker run -it python:3.11-slim-buster /bin/bash
root@201dfe147e5a:/# ls -la /tmp
total 8
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root 4096 Nov 16 06:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jan 29 04:36 ..
```

This was fine a few weeks ago on the Ubuntu machine. I recently moved all the files from `/var/lib/ubuntu` to `/ubuntu` because the partition mounted at `/var` was full. Would this have caused the behavior with the permissions of `/tmp` inside a container? If so, why? And how do I fix it? If not, what else would cause this and...how do I fix it?

Comment: _I recently moved all the files_ Playing with internal Docker files may have unexpected effects. As stated by @Code-Apprentice's answer, you may have applied another permission to these files or unwantedly changed something else. In such situations I'd recommend instead backing-up data from important resources (volumes for instance, see https://docs.docker.com/storage/#good-use-cases-for-volumes) and recreating a fresh Docker install with another setup (use another disk to store data in your case)

Comment: @PierreB. I ended up formatting the entire drive and reinstalling. This is a sledge hammer, but it's what I decided I had to do in my situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker uses a so-called union file system for a running container. The recommended driver on Linux is called `overlay2`. The files and directories for each layer of an image are stored under `/var/lib/docker/overlay2`, assuming the default config. The directory structure for each layer is combined to create the final file system for the container. See https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/ for more details.

As for the permissions for the files in the container, they are derived from the permissions of the files in this directory in the host file system. When I copied the files from `/var/lib/docker` to `/docker`, I failed to preserve ownership and permissions. My best guess is that umask was applied as each new file was created.